# HTML not resizing width of image

Tags: html, css, web

When I make the screen of my browser smaller my image width will not become smaller and I have been trying to use this:

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%
  height: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<img src = "112TP.png" alt = "Shin-Dor Soccer Image">
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: html:         <div class = "container">
  <h3><font size = "+2"><strong>Shin-Dor Soccer</strong></font>
  <img src = "112TP.png" alt = "Shin-Dor Soccer Image">
  </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

in CSS you have to write ";" after every line